# Regular Expression for Japan phone number

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to validate the Japan phone number using the following Regular expression

```
var pattern= /^[0-9-]{10,13}$/i;
```

It should allow only the following formats

- 1234567890
- 123-456-7890
- 12-3456-7890
- 123-4567-8901

But when I try it's returning true

```js
var phone_pattern = /^[0-9-]{10,13}$/i;
var value='-----------';
alert(phone_pattern.test(value));
```

Comment: And your issue is that 10 dashes are allowed according to your regex

Comment: Well, the regexps from https://gist.github.com/terrancesnyder/1345094 and http://www.devcurry.com/2010/03/regular-expression-for-phone-numbers.html do not work with the sample numbers in the OP. However, it is not clear what the rules are for Japanese phone numbers, please state them in the question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for your suggestion, Even I searched googled/stackoverflow many times and also written the regular expression it didn't worked and then only I posted here. I am aware of Stackoverflow guide lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it to be easily understandable I'd just use an alternation of the 4 possible patterns :

```
^(?:\d{10}|\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{4}|\d{3}-\d{4}-\d{4})$
```

This one matches your 4 phone numbers in 50 steps according to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Xc6oo1/1).

If you want it to be a little bit more efficient at the cost of readability, you can factorize it :

```
^\d{2}(?:-\d{4}-\d{4}|\d{8}|\d-\d{3,4}-\d{4})$
```

This one matches your 4 phone numbers in 48 steps according to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sP51Cw/1).

Comment: Aaron, I am almost sure that OP is testing against standalone strings and `^` / `$` around the pattern are necessary.

Comment: Good, but `^(?:\d{2}(?:-\d{4}-\d{4}|\d{8}|\d-\d{3,4}-\d{4}))$` contains redundant outer non-cpaturing group :) Anyway, that will work.

Answer (score -1):

This code has support you! test OK in https://regex101.com/r/9ePPzz/1

```
^(([0-9]{10}$)|([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$)|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$)|([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$))
```

Answer (score -1):

Japanese phone numbers always start with zero.
The regex should start with `^0`.
This is suitable for fixed number in Japan.

```
^0([1-9]{1}-?[1-9]\d{3}|[1-9]{2}-?\d{3}|[1-9]{2}\d{1}-?\d{2}|[1-9]{2}\d{2}-?\d{1})-?\d{4}$
```

Please look here in detail.
https://github.com/sakatam/a-better-jp-phone-regex

Answer (score -1):

Just wanted to mention this in case anyone else is trying to validate Japanese phone numbers as well

There are many phone numbers formats in Japan not covered by just the 5 cases listed in the question [(see Wiki for more details)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Japan)

The regex [mentioned here](https://github.com/sakatam/a-better-jp-phone-regex) covers all (or at least most) of them

In other words this regex is more comprehensive

```
^(0([1-9]{1}-?[1-9]\d{3}|[1-9]{2}-?\d{3}|[1-9]{2}\d{1}-?\d{2}|[1-9]{2}\d{2}-?\d{1})-?\d{4}|0[789]0-?\d{4}-?\d{4}|050-?\d{4}-?\d{4})$
```